# how to pass response of api call from trigger to sidebar component in salesforce?

Tags: javascript, triggers, components, salesforce, sidebar

I am doing a webservice call in a trigger on Lead object and i need to pass the **response back** to the frontend ... that is to the **sidebar component and the javascript** present in it will read the response and act accordingly ...

also is there any way to get the **context of page in the sidebar component**....i mean in what page i am ... that is a lead or oppurtunity or account page.... sidebar component has to know this context...

so what i need is

- pass the response from trigger to sidebar component find the page
- context using the sidebar component

thanks for you suggestions...

Comment: Your question is very confusing; I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. What's the use case? When does the Trigger execute?

Comment: Why are you calling a web service in a Trigger?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way (that I'm aware of) to pass a response to the UI from a Trigger because Triggers are run as a result of database commands (insert, update, delete, etc.). To get data back from a Trigger, you would have to write that data to a record/field then query for it.